# Rails 4: Showing elements sorted on a 'date' attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to make a page that will display a series of upcoming events. The thing is, these events will change every few weeks or so, so I want to be able to continuously update the events when logged in as an admin (I'm using ActiveAdmin).

This `Event` model only has to have a few attributes, namely a `date`, `time`, `location`, and `description`.

There will only ever be <10 events existing at any time, and I want to display them in increasing order of date on a separate page, namely under the `events` action/page under my `StaticPages Controller`. I know that in my `events` action definition (in the `StaticPages Controller`) I can call `@events = Event.all`, which then allows me access to all of the events in the `events` view, but what is the best way to then process (i.e. sort) the `Event` objects to display them in order of increasing date? Is there some sort of Rails helper or structure I can use for this? Thanks.

Comment: Just say `Event.order('date ASC, time ASC')` instead of `Event.all`. By the way, you should use a single field of type `datetime`, not two separate fields.

Comment: I'm sorry.  In Rails 4 it is better to say Event.order(:date => :asc, :time => :asc).  My previous response was good for Rails 3.  But again a single field of type `datetime` will be better.

Comment: Great, thanks. So `Event.order(:date => :asc, :time => :asc)` will return *all* of the Event objects, sorted according to these parameters?

Comment: Sure.  Read the documentation!  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you might be interested in a blog post i did on timezones with rails - http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/ - it has sample code with 'Event' model as well

Comment: You could make it drier by using a [`scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) - `scope :latest, -> { order(date: :asc, time: :asc) }`

Comment: This will allow you to call `Event.latest`

Comment: @RichPeck add this as an answer, I will up vote you. Even if I consider this question a must-close

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Posted bud - thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4):

In order to get the data you seek, you'll basically have to perform an [`order`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) SQL query like how Gene posted (brings back all data but ordered to your specs ):

```
Event.order(date: :asc, time: :asc)
```

However, if you wanted to keep your code DRY, you might want to look at a [`scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes):

```
#app/models/event.rb
Class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :latest, -> { order(date: :asc, time: :asc)}
end
```

This will allow you to call `Event.latest` any time you need!